# How can i select all the row in ObjectListView?

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I'm using [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) in winforms application, and i encountered a problem, in my List i wont if i click on any column of my row it should be selected (all the row).

this is my code:

```
olvSongs.AllColumns.Add(this.titleColumn);
olvSongs.AllColumns.Add(this.typeColumn);
olvSongs.AllColumns.Add(this.addedColumn);
olvSongs.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
olvSongs.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
this.titleColumn,
this.typeColumn,
this.addedColumn});
olvSongs.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 40);
olvSongs.Name = "olvSongs";
olvSongs.ShowGroups = false;
olvSongs.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(638, 190);
olvSongs.SmallImageList = this.imageList1;
olvSongs.TabIndex = 7;
olvSongs.UseAlternatingBackColors = true;
olvSongs.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
olvSongs.UseFiltering = true;
olvSongs.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
```

here i can select the row only if i select `titleColumn`.

this is picture to demonstrate what i get (the selection only on the first column):

[image]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: you can set MultiSelect property to True

Comment: No it dosen't work, i think MultiSelect is for selecting multiple row, but me i wont to select the row when i click on any column. hope it's clear.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is a little bit unclear what you want to achieve., But if you are talking about this

[image]

VS this

[image]

you have to set

```
olvSongs.FullRowSelect = true;
```

If thats not what you mean please improve your question.